# Why am I unable to logout as a user?

Tags: php-errors, logout

I am running EE 3.5.15 and have added the following link to a user page so the user can log out:

```
<a href="{path='logout'}">Log Out</a>
```

However when I click on that link, instead of logging out I get the following error:

[image]

Any clues why this is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: did you check the extention is actually on the server?

Comment: Yes. The extension is there.

Comment: Did you check permissions of file? Try echo exit in constructer.